# Using Matlab to plot y=-log(sin(x))

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I tried:

```
x=linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y=-log(sin(x));
plot(x,y)
grid on
axis([-2*pi,2*pi,-5,10])
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

How can I prevent Matlab from plotting just the real parts of the solution in the intervals where complex numbers are returned?

Comment: Step 1: Decide how a complex variable should be presented.  At least cartesian (real and imaginary components) and polar (magnitude and angle) are entirely valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieved that by separating real and imaginary parts using, respectively, the [real function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) and the [imag function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imag.html). Once this is done, all you have to do is to perform two separate plots on the same axis:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);

y = -log(sin(x));
y_real = real(y);
y_imag = imag(y);

h1 = plot(x,y_real);
grid on;
axis([-2*pi,2*pi,-5,10]);

hold on;
h2 = plot(x,y_imag);
hold off;

legend([h1 h2],'Real Part','Imaginary Part');
```

Below the final result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found an easy way:

```
syms x
fplot(-log(sin(x)),[-2*pi,2*pi],...
    'LineWidth',1)
axis([-2*pi,2*pi,0,8])
grid on
```

Which produces this image:

[image]